# route network traffic based on the subdirectory requested

Tags: apache, proxy, virtualhost, httpd.conf, http-proxy

I have 3 back end nodes to handle traffic but round robin doesn't work in my case.
Is it possible to use Apache web server and route(proxy) all traffic from A-E to server 1, F-S to server 2 and T-Z to server 3? I don't want the url to change.

For example: build.amz.com/TEST should go to server 3 while build.amz.com/ECHO should go to server 1?
I am new to Apache, any directions towards how to achieve this is helpful

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you fix the round robin issue?

Comment: no, i want this ring based topology. all 3 servers are not of equal capacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPassMatch ^/([A-Ka-k]+)(.*) http://server1/$1$2
ProxyPassReverse / http://server1/

ProxyPassMatch ^/([L-Pl-p]+)(.*) http://server2/$1$2
ProxyPassReverse / http://server2/

ProxyPassMatch ^/([Q-Zq-z]+)(.*) http://server3/$1$2
ProxyPassReverse / http://server3/

#ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*) http://serverdefault/$1
#ProxyPassReverse / http://serverdefault/
```

Comment: This should go inside a virtual host or in httpd.conf?

Comment: usually inside VirtualHost

Comment: do you know how the conf scales?  i already have 5000 reverse proxies